# Remove duplicates from a VBA combobox

Tags: vba, list, excel, sorting

Here's what I want to do... I have a big list of stuff in a sheet. I want to add all those (let's say are names) names to a VBA combobox but I want only unique records. I also want to sort them.

I know that I can do that if I sort and remove the duplicates in Excel... but I want to o it from VBA without altering the data in Excel.

Is it possible?

Comment: Would the unique qualifier be case sensitive?

Comment: Duplicate question or overlap with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840343/only-unique-records-in-a-combobox-vba

Comment: @JP. Looks like that one involves only unique values but it doesn't mention sorting does it? I didn't see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only add unqiue items:

```
Sub addIfUnique(CB As ComboBox, value As String)
    If CB.ListCount = 0 Then GoTo doAdd
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To CB.ListCount - 1
        If LCase(CB.List(i)) = LCase(value) Then Exit Sub
    Next
doAdd:
    CB.AddItem value
End Sub
```

Found this code:

```
Sub SortCombo(oCb As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Dim vaItems As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    vaItems = oCb.List
    For i = LBound(vaItems, 1) To UBound(vaItems, 1) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(vaItems, 1)
            If vaItems(i, 0) > vaItems(j, 0) Then
                vTemp = vaItems(i, 0)
                vaItems(i, 0) = vaItems(j, 0)
                vaItems(j, 0) = vTemp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    oCb.Clear
    For i = LBound(vaItems, 1) To UBound(vaItems, 1)
        oCb.AddItem vaItems(i, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested code sorting and removing duplicates in a combobox. It operates on combobox list after all items are added. Adding items to the combobox may be performed using range or file etc, below is just an example.
The main part is the sorting function.
One thing to remember, both functions' object arguments are passed by reference so when calling don't use brackets like so (I got 'Object Required' error when I did):

```
'example of calling function below    
GetItemsFromRange Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A20"), MyComboBox


'Build combobox list from range
Private Function GetItemsFromRange(ByRef inRange As Range, ByRef SampleBox As ComboBox) 
Dim currentcell As Range
For Each currentcell In inRange.Cells
If Not IsEmpty(currentcell.Value) Then
SampleBox.AddItem (Trim(currentcell.Value))
End If
Next currentcell
'call to sorting function, passing combobox by reference, 
'removed brackets due to 'Object Required' error
sortunique SampleBox  
End Function
```

Now this is our sorting function. I used Do-Loop statement because ListCount property may change value when duplicates are removed.

```
Private Function sortunique(ByRef SampleBox As ComboBox)
Dim temp As Object 'helper item for swaps
Dim i As Long 'ascending index
Dim j As Long 'descending index
i = 0 'initialize i to first index in the list 

If SampleBox.ListCount > 1 Then 
'more than one item - start traversing up the list
Do
If SampleBox.List(i, 0) = SampleBox.List(i + 1, 0) Then 
'duplicate - remove current item
SampleBox.RemoveItem (i)
'item removed - go back one index    
i = i - 1 
ElseIf SampleBox.List(i, 0) > SampleBox.List(i + 1, 0) Then 
'if next item's value is higher then the current item's
temp = SampleBox.List(i, 0)
'then make a swap    
SampleBox.List(i, 0) = SampleBox.List(i + 1, 0)
SampleBox.List(i + 1, 0) = temp 
'and if index is more than 0
 If i > 0 Then 
 j = i
 Do  
 'start traversing down to check if our swapped item's value is lower or same as earlier item's
  If SampleBox.List(j - 1, 0) = SampleBox.List(j, 0) Then 
  'if duplicate found - remove it
  SampleBox.RemoveItem (j) 
  'update ascending index (it's decreased for all items above our index after deletion)
  i = i - 1
  'and continue on the way up
  Exit Do 
  ElseIf SampleBox.List(j - 1, 0) > SampleBox.List(j, 0) Then 
  'If item earlier in the list is higher than current
  temp = SampleBox.List(j, 0)
  'make a swap
  SampleBox.List(j, 0) = SampleBox.List(j - 1, 0)
  SampleBox.List(j - 1, 0) = temp 
  Else
  'When no lower value is found - exit loop
  Exit Do 
  End If 
 'update descending index
 j = j - 1 
 'continue if items still left below
 Loop While j > 0 
 End If
End If
'update ascending index
i = i + 1 
'continue if not end of list
Loop While i < SampleBox.ListCount - 1 
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This can remove duplicates very easily, first load the combolist, as an axample:

```
'We fulfill the combolist with the selection, in this case using range
Dim rango, celda As Range
Set rango = Worksheets("ExampleWorksheet").Range("A1:A159")

For Each celda In rango
    Instrument.AddItem celda.Value
Next celda
```

And now you can eliminate the duplicates:

```
'Now we eliminate de duplicates in a single row
For i = 0 To Instrument.ListCount - 2
    For j = Me.Instrument.ListCount - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
        If Instrument.List(i) = Instrument.List(j) Then 'repeated
            Instrument.RemoveItem (j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```