# Only unique records in a Combobox (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox where I add some stuff from an Excel sheet with a bunch of stuff. I want only unique records and I want them to be updated when I switch to this page. 
For that I used the following code:

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
Dim Rand As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("BD_IR")
Dim i As Long
Rand = 3
Do While ws.Cells(Rand, 3).Value <> "" And Rand < 65536
    If Me.repereche.ListCount <> 0 Then
        For i = 0 To (Me.repereche.ListCount)
        If Me.repereche.List(i, 0) <> Mid(ws.Cells(Rand, 3).Value, 4, 10) Then
            Me.Controls("repereche").AddItem Mid(ws.Cells(Rand, 3).Value, 4, 10)
        End If
        Next i
    ElseIf Me.repereche.ListCount = 0 Then
        Me.Controls("repereche").AddItem Mid(ws.Cells(Rand, 3).Value, 4, 10)
    End If
    Rand = Rand + 1
Loop
```

The problem with this code (and I don't know where the problem is?) is that whenever I change the page and I come back to the page where this combobox is... it adds more (not unique) and more items. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You need to clear out the combo box before adding items to it. That will stop the "more and more items" from being added each time you switch pages. If you want unique records, read the range into an array and add each item to a Collection object -- this will allow you to add only unique items because Collection objects reject duplicates. See http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/05/18/listing-unique-items-with-collections/ for sample code.

Comment: `Rand` as a variable name makes me think it should be a random number (as in the `RAND` worksheet function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rCell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("BD_IR")

'//Clear combobox
repereche.Clear

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(rCell.Value) Then
            .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next rCell

    repereche.List = .keys
End With
```

I prefer this over a collection as you can check if the value exists in the dictionary rather than using on error and add the entire collection to the combobox at once.

Comment: Nice code, and good information.  I didn't know about the superiority of a dictionary object over a collection in this regard.

Comment: Great. It's the first one it works as I want it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 dictionaries are also moe efficient time wise than collections