# How to get values in Combobox from Excel Column using Excel vba 2007

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have three columns in excel 2007 like

```
Category  Key    Products

Dairy     22       Milk

Dairy     22       Butter

Dairy     22       Cheez

Color     44       Red

Color     44       Green

Color     44       Blue

Shampoo    1       Pentene

Shampoo    1       H& D

Shampoo    1       Sunsilk

Drink      3       Pepsi

Drink      3       Coke
```

I have one form that contain 1 combobox and 4 textboxes. I want to get unique values in combobox from "category" column. When I select like color then the Color key from "Key" column and relevant "Prodcuts" should be displayed in textboxes. For example. If I select Dairy then One textbox1 should display key "22" and other three textboxes should display "Milk","Butter" and "Cheez".
How to do this using VBA. 
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: For loading only unique values see [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840343/only-unique-records-in-a-combobox-vba/7841418#7841418)

Answer (score 0):

Set the RowSource property of the combo box to the range of the first column and then implement the Change event of the combo box to assign the text box values via the combo box index selected.