# De-duplicate VBA scripting dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I've got three combo boxes in a workbook that I want to daisy chain together. Item lists for each combo box refresh when you hit the down arrow on the keyboard after clicking the drop down button on the combo box. The second combo box list is dependent on the selection made in the first combo box. I've built these using scripting dictionaries.

`strCustComboBox` is the value in the previous combo box that the current combo box should be dependent on.

`rngProject` is looking at a range with lots of quote IDs in it. I offset from this column to the column where the values for the previous combo box are held and if this value is equal to `strCustComboBox` then add `rngCompany` value to the scripting dictionary

I'm running into a problem in the loop where I am trying to de-duplicate the `rngCompany` values written into the scripting dictionary that is used to build the list to be shown in the combo box. My code is below.

```
Sub UpdateComboBox1FromDashData()
Dim strCustComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim strComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim rngCompany As Range
Dim rngProject As Range
Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long

Worksheets("QuoteEditor").Unprotect "xxxx"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set strCustComboBox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QuoteEditor").ComboBox4
Set strComboBox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QuoteEditor").ComboBox1

If strCustComboBox = "" Then

      MsgBox "Please select a project first", vbOKCancel

Else
End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DashboardData").Select

Call FindLastRow("A", "10")

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
c = Range("A10:A" & strLastRow)


Set rngProject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DashboardData").Range("A10:A" & strLastRow)

i = 1

For Each rngCompany In rngProject

    If UCase(rngCompany.Offset(, 7).Value) = UCase(strCustComboBox) Then

         If d.exists(rngCompany) = True Then

         Else
             d.Add rngCompany, i
             i = i + 1

         End If

     Else

     End If

Next rngCompany

For Each Item In d

     strComboBox.AddItem (Item)

Next Item
```

I think where I am using `d.exists(rngCompany)` is wrong but I'm not sure. When the subroutine finishes I still get duplicate data return to the combo box list.

I've also tried the code below as per the suggested duplicate thread:

```
With d

    For Each rngCompany In rngProject

        If UCase(rngCompany.Offset(, 7).Value) = UCase(strCustComboBox) Then

            If Not .exists(rngCompany) Then

                d.Add rngCompany, Nothing

            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next rngCompany
End With
```

Can anyone see where either of these are going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only unique records in a Combobox (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840343/only-unique-records-in-a-combobox-vba)

Comment: @eirikdaude I've tried this. Unless I'm implementing their method incorrectly, which I do not believe I am, the approach doesn't work for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You declare `Dim d as Object` but never initialize/assign it. I'd expect an error when trying to access a member of an empty object... Do `d.Exists` or `D.Add` work as you expect?

Comment: @Inarion Apologies I redacted some of the code I deemed irrelevant to the problem I am having. I've edited the question. Even though I put in steps to check for duplicates, I still get duplicate date in the drop down list when the subroutine has finished running.

Comment: How I'd approach the problem: You've got duplicate values you did not expect. What are the values? They have to be in that worksheet. Compare them. Are they actually duplicates (i.e. binary identical)? Step through your code - do they both get added to the dictionary as separate keys? Are you sure about that? Have a look at the entries in `d` in the locals window when execution has finished the `For Each rngCompany In rngProject` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hid the answer to this in your own question (emphasis mine):

> where I am trying to de-duplicate the rngCompany ***values***

There is no way for `d.Exists(rngCompany)` to return true the way that you have this written, because you are keying the `Dictionary` on the ***range***, not its contents. Since the items you are testing are part of the iteration `For Each rngCompany In rngProject`, you are guaranteed to have only distinct ranges.

The solution is trivial - you need to explicitly call the default member of `rngCompany`:

```
If Not d.Exists(rngCompany.Value) Then
   d.Add rngCompany.Value, i
   i = i + 1   
End If
```

Comment: Whoa... I thought just the dictionary's `Items` could be objects. I did not expect it to also accept them as `Keys`. As such, when asked, I'd have said that VBA would likely access the Range's default member for the key. The more you know... +1

Comment: @Inarion This is precisely why you shouldn't get in the habit of relying on implicit default member access.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Comintern I completely missed this. I've made the amendment, but unfortunately it's still not working - I still end up with duplicates so I think I'm missing something in the steps.

Comment: @AndrewBuchanan Can you verify these are actually duplicates? An additional space (or any other symbol) will make for a different entry. Can you fabricate an example that exhibits this behavior and which you can show us?

Comment: @Inarion They're definitely not duplicates - I'm pulling this data down from a SQL database that trims all table elements etc. Do you know of somewhere where I can host a file that you can look at?

Comment: @AndrewBuchanan I'm not asking for a huge file, but for a small and simple example. Trim down the data set as much as possible and present what remains in your question (5 entries should be enough to demonstrate the behavior). This is as much for our sake as it is for yours. Simplify the problem until it stops happening. Eliminate the noise around it. Then you'll likely know where to look at.

Comment: @Inarion sorry when I said not duplicates I meant they definitely are duplicates. Ok I'll see what I can do and come back to you. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @AndrewBuchanan Did you change the `d.Add rngCompany, i` to `d.Add rngCompany.Value, i` too?

Comment: @Comintern That's fixed it! I've edited your answer to include that also. I'll accept it. Thank you!